# Bremsstrahlung photon energy query

Tags: atomic-physics, radiation, x-rays

In my textbook they've defined the energy of a photon released by an electron decelerated by a nucleus to be the difference in its KE before and after being decelerated by the nucleus. However I was wondering why we don't need to subtract the energy gained by the nuclei?

I understand its more massive and so its velocity gain will be negligible, but shouldn't it still gain a non negligible fraction of the initial KE of the electron?

Comment: The massiveness of the nucleus makes the center of mass electron-nucleus almost the same as the electron hitting nuleus at rest. ( similar a ball hitting a wall bounces off with -p because the very large mass of the wall matches 2p within measurement errors). If you go to the trouble to do the calculation you will see it is within possible errors and the HUP.